# Terraform use_msi on azurerm_function_app

Tags: terraform, azure-function-app

I'm trying to run a terraform plan with an azurerm_function_app. I have this provider:

```
provider "azuread" {
  use_msi = true
}
```

and this in my azurerm_function_app block:

```
  identity = {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
```

Unfortunately my plan keeps saying:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 62, in resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example":
  62:     identity = {

An argument named "identity" is not expected here.
```

I have added a SystemAssigned identity in the portal, but my terraform plan does not pick it up.

How can I add a MSI to azurerm_app_service_plan?

Comment: It is a block and not an argument, so try changing to `identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }`.

Comment: Seems like I messed up. I'll give it a try as soon as I can get to the keyboard. Thanks, I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, that was the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `azurerm_function_app` resource, the `identity` is documented as a block and not an argument. While an argument would require the syntax of a `=` immediately following it (and could possibly contain a map type with `{}` syntax), a block requires the syntax of `{}` following it. The block would contain whatever arguments are relevant.

Therefore, we can update your resource accordingly to fit the syntax requirements:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "my_function" {
  ...
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  ...
}
```

and fix the error.